# Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, then $A\subset X$ is compact $\iff$ A is closed

Tags: general-topology

So I was trying to see if anyone could confirm the veracity of this statement. I've done the prove and I would like to know if I've done it right. This is a caracterization of the closed subsets inside a compact Hausdorff space (see demonstration).

$\Rightarrow)$ To prove this implication I will only use that $X$ is Hausdorff, without using the fact that it is also compact. So, we are trying to see is that $X$ Hausdorff, let $A\subset X$ compact, then A is closed.

> To prove this statement we will see that $X\setminus A$ is open because all it's points are interior. So, let $x\in X\setminus A$ be any point, we need to find a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$, such that
> $$x\in\mathcal{U}\subset X\setminus A$$
> Let $a\in A$ and $x\in X\setminus A$, as $X$ is Hausdorff, we can find two distinct neighbourhoods $\mathcal{U}_a$ and $\mathcal{V}_a$ such that $x\in \mathcal{U}_a$, $a\in \mathcal{V}_a$ and $\mathcal{U}_a\cap\mathcal{V}_a=\emptyset$. Doing this process for all points in $A$, we get
> $$a\in \bigcup_{a\in A}\mathcal{V}_a:=\mathcal{V}\subset X, \hspace{4mm} x\in \bigcap_{a\in A}\mathcal{U}_a:=\mathcal{U}\subset X\setminus A$$
> where $a\in \mathcal{V}$, $x\in \mathcal{U}$, and $\mathcal{V}\cap\mathcal{U}=\emptyset$. Notice that $\mathcal{V}$ is open (because it is an arbitrary union of open sets), but we cannot garantee that $\mathcal{U}$ is open. Now, as $A$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover $\{\mathcal{V}_{a_{i}}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that
> $$a\in \bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal{V}_{a_i}:=\mathcal{V'}\subset X, \hspace{4mm} x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{U}_{a_i}:=\mathcal{U'}\subset X\setminus A$$
> So, we have constructed a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U'}$ such that $x\in \mathcal{U'}\subset X\setminus A$. As all points in $X\setminus A$ are interior, this means that $X\setminus A$ is open so $A$ is closed.

$\Leftarrow$) To prove this other implication I will only use the fact that $X$ is compact. So, we are trying to see that $X$ compact, let $A\subset X$ closed, then $A$ is compact.

> Let's starts by considering a cover of $A$ and see that it admits a finite subcover.
> $$\{\mathcal{W}_a\}_{a\in A}, \hspace{4mm} A\subset\bigcup_{a\in A}\mathcal{W}_a$$
> which is open (because it is an arbitrary union of open sets). Now, observe that we can create a cover of $X$ just by adding one more open set. $$X\subset \bigcup_{a\in A}\mathcal{W}_a\cup(X\setminus A)$$ $X\setminus A$ is open because $A$ is closed. As $X$ is compact, we can find a finite subcover of $X$, but the only way for $X$ to admit a finite subcover is that there exists a family of open sets $\{\mathcal{W}_{a_i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ such that
> $$X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{W}_{a_i}\cup (X\setminus A)$$
> But now, $\{\mathcal{W}_{a_i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a finite subcover of open sets such that $A\subset \{\mathcal{W}_{a_i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ $\hspace{7mm} \blacksquare$

So, as we saw, does this mean that inside a compact Hausdorff space $X$, the closed and compact subsets are exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both sides are correct. In a compact space, all closed subsets are also compact (compactness is closed-hereditary). And in a Hausdorff space a compact subset is closed ( also expressible as “Hausdorff implies KC”, as implication between two topological properties).